# removing the string character in integer value : Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i want to remove the string character from `int` value in a list. when i remove `str` character from below statement then it's throw me `TypeError`: `'int' object is not iterable`. how can i achieve that?

```
for record in serializer.data:
    if record:
        less_eight = [x for x in str(record['car_cc'])]
        print(less_eight)
    else:
        #some logic
```

output:

```
['8', '0', '0']
['5', '0', '0']
```

what i want is:

```
[8, 0, 0]
[5, 0, 0]
```

Comment: `[int(x) for x in str(record['car_cc'])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited to join the result:

```py
for record in serializer.data:
    if record:
        less_eight = [int(''.join(x)) for x in str(record['car_cc'])]
        print(less_eight)
    else:
        #some logic
```

Comment: how to remove the comma in this list as well?

Comment: `less_eight = [int(x) for x in str(record['car_cc']).split(',')]`    is it wrong?

Comment: well I don't know how your original data looks. What you have posted there will translate the `record['car_cc']`to a string, and then split that string into a list every time a comma is encountered. My posted solution simply joins the list of strings back into one string and then converts it to an integer. So it depends on what you want

Comment: your edited answer doesn't remove the comma, instead it giving the result what i was needed the first. It's okay. much appreciated.

Comment: the comma is not a comma but a separator for the list entries

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap it with `int()`

```py
for record in serializer.data:
    if record:
        less_eight = [int(x) for x in str(record['car_cc'])]
        print(less_eight)
    else:
        #some logic
```

Answer (score 2):

in the out put you must determine that less_eight is integer :

```
for record in serializer.data:
    if record:
        less_eight = [x for x in str(record['car_cc'])]
        print(int(less_eight))
    else:
        #some logic
```

Comment: you can not remove the comma because this is a list and lists have comma for having more than one objects

Comment: `less_eight = [int(x) for x in str(record['car_cc']).split(',')]`    is it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure about it